# Lossing randomness in sklearn model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am encountering a very weird situation.

I am trying to use SVM in sklearn for a binary classification task. Here is my code:

```
  scaler = StandardScaler()
  x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
  x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)

  svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced', gamma='auto',probability=True)
  
  c_range = np.logspace(-5, 15, 11, base=2)
  gamma_range = np.logspace(-9, 3, 13, base=2)
  param_grid = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'C': c_range, 'gamma': gamma_range}]
  grid = GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
  clf = grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
  predictions = grid.predict(x_test)
```

As you can see, this is a very simple model where `x_train` is the input for training data, `x_test` is the input for testing data and `y_train` is the label for training data.

My question is, since I didn't set any seed, why did this code always reproduce the same results? In my understanding, the randomness should exists in my model and there should be at least a few variant results.

---

Let me be a little bit clear, I am not complaining my model only predicts the same class for all the testing data. I am complaining that even I set different seed, my model still produces the consistent results.

For example, assuming I have 3 testing data. When I set seed to 1 or 2 or others, the predictions for testing data are always [1,0,1].

---

I have tried to set different seed, changing random_state in the model. Nothing works.
My training data is very small, only a couple hundred. Testing data is larger, with thousands of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will return different class probabilities for different values of `random_state` in SVC. The fact that the predicted classes are identical across different runs simply means that there is not much ambiguity about the classes the data points belong to. In other words, if your data points look like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier#/media/File:Svm_separating_hyperplanes.png), they are easily separable and models with different seeds will assign the same classes to the same points.

In practice, if a first model assigns for instance to a data point the probabilities {A: 0.942, B: 0.042, C: 0.016} and another model with a different seed assigns the probabilities {A: 0.917, B: 0.048, C: 0.035}, then both models will predict the same class A for this point.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV

data = load_wine()
X = data.data
y = data.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced', gamma='auto', probability=True, random_state=50)

c_range = np.logspace(-5, 15, 11, base=2)
gamma_range = np.logspace(-9, 3, 13, base=2)
param_grid = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'C': c_range, 'gamma': gamma_range}]
grid = GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
clf = grid.fit(x_train, y_train)

predictions = grid.predict_proba(x_test)
print(predictions)
```

Also, most of your data should be used for training, not for testing.